# how is it possible to use flowtype to define a prop in react context of a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

When using [flowtype](http://flowtype.org) to define a prop in the [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) in this way

```
// @flow
type MyType = Object;
class CustomView extends React.Component {
    static childContextTypes = {
        someProp: MyType
    }
    getChildContext() {
        return {
            someProp: this.props.someProp
        };
    }
}
```

I got the following error:

> CustomView: type specification of child context `someProps` is
>   invalid; the type checker function must return `null` or an `Error`
>   but returned a object. You may have forgotten to pass an argument to
>   the type checker creator (arrayOf, instanceOf, objectOf, oneOf,
>   oneOfType, and shape all require an argument).

So I am forced to use `propTypes.object` instead of `Object`.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot use a Flow type as a type in `childContextTypes`. The reason is that `childContextTypes` is checked at runtime, and Flow types do not have any runtime representation. Therefore the "types" in `childContextTypes` must be values - specifically the values provided by the [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) npm package.

The use of `MyType` in your example is actually a syntax error: `MyType` appears in the position of an object property value which must be a value, not a type.