# React Prop Types vs Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

If I use typescript in my project, would that make the usage of prop-types in React obsolete? With prop-types I would have to go through the grunt of defining types but with typescript, this step would be negated. AM I correct in my thinking?

Comment: You might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065185/react-proptypes-vs-flow

Comment: You still need to "define types" with TypeScript, e.g. use an interface to specify the types of your component props. The difference is that when you do the wrong thing, you should end up with a compile error (good) rather than a runtime error (bad). I don't think you need both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds about right. When you use TypeScript you can define the props via an interface.

```
interface ButtonProps {
  text: string,
  shadow?: boolean
}

const Button: React.FunctionComponent<ButtonProps> = props => {
  return ( /* [...] */ );
};
```

See [here](https://dbushell.com/2017/04/19/typescript-instead-of-react-proptypes/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need prop types if you use typewriting. Typescript is a good solution for strong typing, but for this you need to write more code. Props Types provide you efficient typization and small code blocks for you classes or functional components